# Find $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\sin(1-x)}{2-2x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have an assignment about limits:

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{\sin(1-x)}{2-2x}$$

It tells me to calculate the value of the limit.
I observed that it comes up $\frac{\sin (-\infty)}{-\infty}$, so the sin of infinite can't exist. I was just about to solve it, when I decided to try to use Microsoft Math Solver to verify that I was right. But, surprisingly, it told me that the result is 1. Can someone explain why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Result cannot be 1.

Comment: The solver you used has a bug. [WA gets it right](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+sin%281-x%29%2F%282-2x%29+as+x+tends+to+inf).

Comment: You should more think about how the functions in the nominator and denominator behave. Is it possible that you meant that $x$ goes to $1$? If so, then you have to either know or prove that $\sin(x)$ behaves like $x$ for very small numbers. You can try and put small and smaller numbers in a calculator and actually see that this series does indeed converges to $1$. Did this help?

Answer (score 3):

Using the fact that $|\sin(x)| \le 1$ you have the following:

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left| \frac{\sin(1-x)}{2-2x} \right| \le \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{|2-2x|} = 0$$

This concludes that $$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{\sin(1-x)}{2-2x} = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

The sine function only takes real numbers as input and it does not make sense to write $\sin(+\infty)$.

Instead, you should get that
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{1}{2-2x}=0
$$
and $\sin(1-x)$ is **bounded**.

Now look for the property in your notes/book that
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)g(x)=0
$$
if $\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=0
$
and $g(x)$ is a bounded function.